# Ограничить выборку данных только именами таблиц

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется запрос и как применить ограничения по именам таблиц. БД Oracle

```
select uc.table_name "Таблица", 
   uc.constraint_name "Огр внеш ключа", 
   ucc1.column_name "Поле внеш ключа", 
   ucc2.table_name "Родит таблица", 
   uc.r_constraint_name "Огр в РТ", 
   ucc2.column_name "Поле ключа в РТ"
from user_constraints uc 
 join user_cons_columns ucc1 on ucc1.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
 join user_cons_columns ucc2 on ucc2.constraint_name = uc.r_constraint_name
where uc.constraint_type = 'R';
```

Comment: `WHERE uc.TABLE_NAME IN ( {список таблиц} )`. Одноимённое поле есть и в `user_cons_columns`.

Comment: @Akina, а вот это  "where uc.constraint_type = 'R';" уже не нужен?

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно надо получить. Если только FK - нужен.

Comment: @Akina, прошу прощения, код работает как то не так. Я без скобок  ввёл вот так 
WHERE uc.table_name in 'EMPLOYEES'
Вывелось без проблем. А как вывести определённое количество таблиц? Перепробовал варианты с and  и & запрос ошибкой, что неверный символ. 
Подскажите, как правильно написать код чтобы запрос сработал с несколькими таблицами.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions014.htm#SQLRF52169 и https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions016.htm#SQLRF52099

Comment: @Akina разобрался с добавлением таблиц. Спасибо. 
А вот что имеете в виду  "Одноимённое поле есть и в user_cons_columns. " ? Приношу извинение за глупый вопрос,

Comment: Я имею в виду, что если Вы собрались пользоваться добытым откуда-то кодом, то сначала полностью разберитесь, как он работает, что использует, и почему именно так. В данном конкретном случае - изучите структуру используемых системных представлений и то, что именно они возвращают.